# sharedPreferences help. How do I save an int?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to save an int.  All I want to do is save `leftCounter` into a file and retrieve it whenever I reboot my code.

```
public class SalesTrack extends Activity {

   byte leftCounter = 0;
   byte centerCounter = 0;
   byte rightCounter = 0;
   int total;
   int x, y, z;

   public static final String PREFS = "data";

   TextView counterAAL, counterUPG, counterNL, counterTotal;

   private final String LEFTY = "6";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_track);

       counterAAL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_number);
       counterUPG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.center_number);
       counterNL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_number);
       counterTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

       SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(LEFTY, 0);
       sharedPref.getInt("data", leftCounter);
       counterAAL.setText(PREFS);
   }

   public void LeftInc(View v) {
       leftCounter++;
       counterAAL.setText("" + leftCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   public void LeftDec(View v) {
       leftCounter--;
       counterAAL.setText("" + leftCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   public void CenterInc(View v) {
       centerCounter++;
       counterUPG.setText("" + centerCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   public void CenterDec(View v) {
       centerCounter--;
       counterUPG.setText("" + centerCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   public void RightInc(View v) {
       rightCounter++;
       counterNL.setText("" + rightCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   public void RightDec(View v) {
       rightCounter--;
       counterNL.setText("" + rightCounter);
       Refresh();
   }

   // Refresh Total after every click.
   public void Refresh() {
       x = leftCounter * 10;
       y = centerCounter * 20;
       z = rightCounter * 35;
       total = x + y + z;
       counterTotal.setText("" + total);

       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
       editor.putInt("data", leftCounter);
       editor.commit();
   }
}
```

Comment: where r u getting problem to store a int in sharedpreference my suggestion is to convert int  into string and store it.Did u tried it???

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in your code.

```
// SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0); (This line is wrong)
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(LEFTY, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
      editor.putInt("data", leftCounter);
      editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

so you get the data from the file but it's detected as `String` ?

you can use the parse function to convert the `String` into `Integer`

```
int counter = Integer.parseInt(stringvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the preferences with two different names `LEFTY` and `PREFS`.  Given the names, I think you want to change the following line in your `onCreate`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(LEFTY, 0);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(LEFTY, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref .edit();               
editor.putInt("data", leftCounter);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("data", leftCounter);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your `data` inside preference named `PREFS` and fetching through preference name`LEFTY`

Try to change your preference name from `LEFTY` to `PREFS` under `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
...
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
}
```